# Monaco Editor Monarch: Tokenizing Parentheses

Tags: tokenize, monaco-editor

I am having issues with the MonarchTokensProvider. In my application i am writing some custom auto-complete and need to be able to identify opening/closing parentheses.

As such, i expect the tokenizer to tokenize '()' to '(', ')'. However using default settings from monaco, parentheses that are next to each other are grouped together.

**monaco-editor version:** 0.30.1
**Browser:** Firefox, Chrome, Safari
**OS:** MacOS
**Playground code that reproduces the issue:**
See:
https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html

- Press F1 and select 'Developer: Inspect Tokens'.
- Move the cursor to the parentheses at 'main()'. See that '()' is listed as a single token.

Does anyone know the regex i need to use for the parentheses?
Overall i've only seen this being used

```
      // delimiters and operators
      [/[{}()\[\]]/, '@brackets'],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify what you want to be interpreted as any monarch tokenizer class you want:

```js
// [/[{}()\[\]]/, "@brackets"],
[/\(/, "openingparenthesis"],
[/\)/, "closingparenthesis"],
[/{/, "openingcurlybrace"],
[/}/, "closingcurlybrace"],
[/\]/, "openingbracket"],
[/\[/, "closingbracket"],
```

Comment: There's still an issue (even with this approach) where same parenthesis are grouped as single token, for example ")))" - will be counted as one token.

Comment: Then I do not think Monarch tokenizer allows you to achieve what you want. If I understand correctly how it works, contiguous tokens with the same name will be grouped together in the final tokenization.

Comment: Yeah, I came to the same conclusion. The solution I went with is splitting those tokens with custom code.